# JavaScript Popup to save modification on a page

Tags: javascript, web

When I modify my email and I want to leave that page, Gmail sends a popup with a message of "changes you made may not be saved" with two button leave and cancel.

How should I make a popup like that in javascript? I put the sample of the popup in the follow. Sorry, I didn't know anything about JS.

[image]

Comment: Show us an example of what you have tried or googled...

Comment: The answers below are more than helpful to help you achieve what you want to do. But you should visit: https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp for great Js tutorials

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve desired result by adding a listener to `beforeunload` event for `window`. Here's an example from MDN:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

To test the code above, run this into browser console and try to closing the browser tab.

For more detailed guide, look into MDN [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Example).

Answer (score 0):

This popup is a "alert popup".

You can display a simple one with `alert()` function.

Or one with a confirm/cancel with `confirm()` function.

you can find more info there https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp (on alert popup and js in general)